# Migrate existing data when altering the column type from string to json

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an existing column type `varchar`. I need to convert this column type to new type `jsonb`. The problem is if the column has already data `'str1:str2'` then after converting the type to `jsonb` column has invalid JSON string `'str1:str2'`.
I want to migrate the existing string `'str1:str2'` into the proper JSON string with keys as `'{"key1":"str1","key2":"str2"}'` before/while converting the column type.
Is it possible to do it using `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN....Using function()` clause or in some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making up any keys, why not convert that to a json array?

```
alter table the_table
  alter column the_column type jsonb 
  using to_jsonb(string_to_array(the_column, ':'));
```

That would turn `str1:str2` into `["str1", "str2"]`

If you really need to make up some (numbered keys), you will have to write a helper function:

```
create function make_json_keys(p_input text)
returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg('key'||idx, val)
  from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, ':')) with ordinality as t(val, idx);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

That can be used in the USING expression:

```
alter table the_table
  alter column the_column type jsonb 
  using make_json_keys(the_column);
```

Comment: the  data does not have any keys but only values. Values are separated via ':' and are in same order. I guess json always has key value pair so I want to add "key" also .

Comment: @NeerajBansal: so where does the "key" come from? Sounds as if a JSON array made more sense

Comment: This I know as hardcoded value that current column has values 'str1:str2:str3' corresponding to the keys 'key1:key2:key3'. Earlier I was fetching the data and parsing string by splitting it and was mapping it to keys. But now it is having lot of rows and to make search query faster based on keys thought of converting it into json and adding index on it.

Comment: @NeerajBansal: see my edit

Comment: Mostly this function approach will work for me, but my keys are not numbered. Seems I have to do some extra work in function to convert the existing string into json string with keys and then into json object.

Comment: @NeerajBansal: well in your question you turned them into numbered keys...

Comment: @a_horse_with_nom Is it  possible to concat two array of key and value into json object?